# Como mascarar a URL depois de esconder um GET com history.pushState?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho uma página de busca em meu sistema. Devido a paginação estou usando os dados do form via GET. Porém, quando vou pesquisar algo o URL fica, por exemplo:

```
http://sistema.com/busca.php?nome=silva
```

Pesquisando eu achei um "workaround" que depois de ter feito a busca ele volta o URL normal, não deixando visível para o usuário. Usei isto:

```
if(typeof window.history.pushState == 'function') {
        window.history.pushState({}, "Hide", "http://sistema.com/busca.php");
}
```

À principio funciona, com algum *delay* (deixa o usuário ver como um flash e já altera o URL), mas funciona.

O problema é quando eu pressiono o "Voltar" do browser. Ele deixa o URL com os parâmetros novamente. Como resolver essa volta do browser? Existe uma forma mais elegante de mascarar esses parâmetros?

Comment: O ideal é usar o método POST, assim a busca não fica no URL. A API de Histórico não foi feita para isso. Paginação em post é tranquilo, basta usar campos hidden. E, no pior dos casos, você pode misturar GET com POST se precisar, mandando os campos com POST, mas montando URLs com parâmetros (apesar de não ser o ideal).

Comment: Eu estava usando POST, mas acabou dando alguns problemas na paginação. Exemplo: quando eu ia da primeira para a segunda página, a query se perdia, não respeitava a busca que eu estava fazendo e voltava a seu estado inicial.

Comment: O ideal é consertar o problema, mas fazer do jeito certo. Querer improvisar geralmente acaba dando em mais problemas. Se não deu certo, faltou alguma etapa do conhecimento. Sugeriria se empenhar mais na parte do POST para ter uma aplicação que não vai te dar dor de cabeça no futuro. No começo pode ser chato resolver, mas é um conhecimento que vai te servir pra um monte de coisa em outras situações. Entender como trabalhar com POST e GET é uma coisa essencial para aplicações web.

Comment: Ok, concordo. Mas assim, quando vc diz: "basta usar campos hidden". Esse tipo de campo não é aquele que é invisível ao usuário? Como ele iria usar?

Comment: Nos campo hidden você vai por a busca atual, e o numero da página desejada. O campo que ele digita vai ser normal, e nao hidden.

Comment: Porque não fazer esse pedido via AJAX e mudar somente o conteudo da página?

Comment: @Bacco obg, vou dar uma pesquisada sobre como fazer isso. Sergio, sinceramente, porque não sei como haha.. Algum link que pudesse me ajudar?

Comment: @ziad.ali preciso fazer outras coisas agora, mas se eu achar uma referência boa, te passo depois. Domine o GET e o POST, pois são coisas que você vai encontrar a toda hora.

Comment: Beleza @Bacco valeu!

Comment: ziad, Ajax parece dificil no começo mas não tem muito mistério, e depois que vc pega o jeito, não vai mais querer parar de usar ;)

Comment: Você poderia usar o .htaccess

Comment: Concordo com o @KhaosDoctor, .htaccess você pode criar uma regra que reescreva sua URL.

Answer (score 0):

No lugar de `pushState` use `replaceState`, comigo funciona muito bem, e também pode usar `setTimeout` para chamar uma função de `limpar a url ()` depois de um tempo se quiser um *delay*.
Caso queira um exemplo fiz uma função em JQuery para meu uso, é só adaptar de acordo com a sua necessidade:

```
function limpaUrl() {     //função
    urlpg = $(location).attr('href');   //pega a url atual da página
    urllimpa = urlpg.split("?")[0]      //tira tudo o que estiver depois de '?'

    window.history.replaceState(null, null, urllimpa); //subtitui a url atual pela url limpa
}

setTimeout(limpaUrl, 4000) //chama a função depois de 4 segundos
```

Comment: São não funciona no IE.

Answer (score 0):

Faça algo como isso [uma pena que `replaceState` não funciona no IE 7,8 e 9]:

```
function recoverUrlNotParams() { 
 var params = window.location.search;
 var url = window.location.pathname;
 if (window.history.replaceState) {
                    window.history.replaceState('Object', this.title,  url);
                } else {
                    //para o IE vc tem que redirecionar
                     if (url.indexOf(params) != -1) {
                        window.location.href = url;
                    }
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu juntei a respostas dos comentário do @Sergio, @Baccon.

Seja na [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1an5j7r2/1/)

#### HTML

```
<div id="conteudo"></div>
<form name="paginacao" id="paginacao" method="post" action="javascript:void(0)">
    <input name="pag" id="pag" type="hidden"/>
    <div>
        <p class="left pagina_1">1</p>
        <p class="left pagina_2">2</p>
        <p class="left pagina_3">3</p>
        <p class="left pagina_4">4</p>
        <p class="left pagina_5">5</p>
    </div>
</form>
```

#### JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('form#paginacao').on('click', 'p', function(){
        var pagina = parseInt(jQuery(this).text());
        jQuery('input#pag').val(pagina);
        jQuery('form#paginacao').submit();
    });

     jQuery('form#paginacao').on('submit', function(){
         var pagina = jQuery(this).find('input#pag').val();
         alert(pagina);
         // AQUI VOCE CRIA UM AJAX
         /*
         jQuery.ajax({
            url: {url},
            data: 'pagina='+pagina,
            success: function(msg){
                jQuery('#conteudo').html(msg);
            }
         });
         */
     });

});
```

Comment: @Sergio, fique a vontade para editar, pois você manja mais que eu.